# Access a control in user control and master page value in User control

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i access a control value in user control  in master page and master page control value in user control?

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're best bet is to make public properties in the user control in a similar fashion as below:

```
public TextBox getMyTextBox()
{
    return this.myTextBox;
}
```

This will give the master page access to the control as a whole. If you are only interested in getting a single value or two then do this:

```
public String getMyTextBoxValue()
{
    return this.myTextBox.Text;
}
```

Depending on what you want to be able to access in your user control from the master page, you can pass in a reference to that object when creating the user control (as a parameter in the constructor)

```
private object needObject;

public MyUserControl(object objectToReference)
{
     this.needObject = objectToReference;
}
```

This way you will have a reference to the object. This will be easy if you're creating the controls 'on the fly - dynamically'. If you want them in your form design from the very start then make a separate method to set the reference for you.

```
public void setParentReference(object objectToReference)
{
    this.needObject = objectToReference;
}
```

In the master page you can simply call this method on your given usercontrol passing in whatever object you need (as long as it's not a primitive, if it is a primitive value then use `ref` to pass as a reference because primitives send value by default) as a parameter and from that point on the usercontrol will have access to the object.

Of course this is just an example of storing reference to a simple object (you can pass in some class which you want to share or any other value.)

If you want to access the parent inside your usercontrol then you should keep in mind that `Control.Parent` gives you access to the parent of the current control.

Since `UserControl` class inherits from `ContentControl` which in turn inherits from `Control` you can simply do this.

```
object parentReference = this.Parent;
```

It is a better practice to use `object` here and then check if it's is a `typeof` form because if it is in a container then the container will be stored and it could cause exception if the variable type was `Form`.

You can also use this to get the ParentForm.

```
Form parentReference = this.ParentForm;
```

But a thing to keep in mind is that if you have just created this dynamic control and haven't yet added it to any form or control childrens list the Parent and ParentForm will be `null` so make sure you validate for `null` before using it or trying to cast it as something.

Then you can use any property from the form by doing this. I assume your master form is called Form1. (`public partial class Form1 : Form`)

```
((Form1)parentReference).somePublicProperty = someValue;
```

Hope it clears it up for you.

Comment: Thanks Mr Daniel Wardin  for the answer. The way it has been formed is well appreciated.