# how to pass result value to master page from user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am developing sample application in asp.net using master and custom controls i have user control page which contain two text box and submit button ,i just take input from two text boc and just display to master page ..
here is code :

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebUserControl1" %>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtA" runat="server" />
<p>
</p>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtB" runat="server" />
<p />

<asp:Button ID="btn01" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="btn01_Click" />


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        public delegate void SendMessageDelegate(string message);

        public event SendMessageDelegate sendMsg;



        protected void btn01_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            decimal dec01 = Convert.ToDecimal(txtA.Text);

            decimal dec02 = Convert.ToDecimal(txtB.Text);

            decimal dectotal = dec01 + dec02;

            if (sendMsg != null)
            {
                sendMsg(dectotal.ToString());
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this [thread][1] maybe can help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040421/access-a-control-in-user-control-and-master-page-value-in-user-control

Comment: At what moment in your master page cycle do you need to know the button was clicked? Inside the Page_Load event or it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a public propertie in your user control and call this in the webpage you have placed the usercontrol in. To pass in to the masterpage you can do this:

```
((MasterPage)this.Master).SomeValue = SomeValue;
```

Comment: If you create a public property on your usercontrol you can access it in de code of the page you put the usercontrol on. So if you would do this in your usercontrol:
`public string SomeValue {get; set;}`

You could use this in the code behind of you aspx page and use the above code to pass it to your masterpage. (replace MasterPage with the class name of your own masterpage.